# MEAN: A file uploaded ignores completely the req.on() NodeJS method

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

I'm using MEAN.IO for developing a webapp.

At this momento, i'm trying to accomplish an uploader for images. For that, i'm using angular-file-upload and it seems to work pretty well.

My problem is at server side. I have something like this:

```
exports.upload = function(req, res, next) {

  console.log(root.process.env.PWD);   // OK

  var uploadPath  = path.normalize(root.process.env.PWD + '/uploads'),
      file        = req.files.file,   // file itself
      data        = new Buffer(''),
      imgURL      = undefined;        // public URL to show the pic


  console.log(file.name);   // OK
  console.log(file.path);   // OK
  console.log(uploadPath);  // OK

  if( !fs.existsSync(uploadPath) ){
        console.log('Creating directory.');
        fs.mkdirSync(uploadDir, 0755);
  }

  req.on('data', function(chunk) {

    console.log('Receiving data');
    data = Buffer.concat( [data, chunk] );

  })
  .on('end', function() {

    console.log('Data received');

    // Writing file to hard disk
    fs.writeFile(uploadPath, data, function(err) {
      if ( err ) {

        console.log('Error saving the uploaded header image.');

        return res.status(500).json({
          error: 'Cannot upload the image'
        });
      }

      console.log('Header image properly uploaded and saved.')

      // Creating the public URL to send it out
      imgURL = '/uploads/' + file.name;
      console.log(imgURL);

      res.json(imgURL);
    });

  });

  console.log('Finished');
};
```

When I put the comment // OK in a console.log is because it prints what it must print (so works as expected).

My main problem is

```
console.log('Receiving data');
```

and

```
console.log('Data received');
```

are not printed, so the execution flow totally ignores both req.on() methods. I have no doubt why, but i'm sure it must be something i have forgotten.

The

```
console.log('Finished');
```

is printed properly, so the execution finishes without any kind of problem or exception.

Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT:

In routes.js, I had added this (i forgot to mention it):

```
'use strict';

var Media = require('../controllers/Media'),
    multipart  = require('connect-multiparty');

var multipartMiddleware = multipart();

var hasAuthorization = function(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.user.isAdmin) {
    return res.send(401, 'User is not authorized.');
  }
  next();
};

module.exports = function(Media, app, auth, database) {

  app.route('/media/upload/header')
    .post(multipartMiddleware, auth.requiresLogin, hasAuthorization, Media.upload);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found myself in a similar situation I just forgot to set up a middleware for requesting file, in this case [busboy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/busboy) did the trick!

in your express config just do this:

```
var busboy = require('connect-busboy');
```

then

```
app.use(busboy());
```

in your controller:

```
exports.upload = function(req, res) {
    var fstream;
    req.pipe(req.busboy);

    req.busboy.on('file',function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype){
        console.log('uploading file:'+mimetype);

        file.on('data',function(data){

        });

        file.on('end', function(){

        });
    });
};
```

Comment: I've edited the main entry. I forgot to mention that i was already using a middleware. Though i don't know if it is properly used. What do you think?

Comment: sometimes routes have a weird behavior try to replace the verb post with all, and check the request! app.route('/media/upload/header')
    .all(multipartMiddleware, auth.requiresLogin, hasAuthorization, Media.upload);

Comment: anyway take a look to busboy seems to have more documentation, cheers!